# Why does jquery append changes link syntax?

Tags: jquery, hyperlink, append

I try to dynamically add a link with a button in a form with 'append' but the syntax of the link appears ends up being different Oo

```
<tr><td class='proposition_container'><span><a href=/link/16/>example</a></span></td></tr>
```

gives :

```
<tr><td class='proposition_container'><span><a href=/link/16/></a>example</span></td></tr>
```

I try to dynamically add a link with a button in a form with 'append' but the syntax of the link appears ends up being different Oo

example

gives

example

I have stripped my case down to a minimum. [See the JSFiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/proph73/kf5vemd9/1/)

HTML :

```
<form action="" method="POST" class="add_link">
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>youpo</th>
  </tr>
      <tr>
          <td class='proposition_container'><span><a href=/liens/16/>Lorem Ipsum</a></td>
      </tr>
  <tr>
    <th> ... </th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
      <th><a href=""><input class="btn" value=" + "></a></th>
  </tr>

</table>
<input type="text" class="form-control-plaintext" placeholder="Link to add" name="lie" oninput="myFunction(this.value)">
<input type="submit" value="Ajouter">
</form>
```

JS :

```
$('.add_link').on('submit', function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        var $form = $(this);
        var $table = $form.find("table");
        var $bouton = $('input[type="submit"]', $form);

        var $lien = "<tr><td class='proposition_container'><span><a href=/link/16/>blup</a></span></td></tr>";
        $table.append($lien);
        });
```

Comment: Typo.  You forgot to put quotes around the `href` attribute, which appears to be confusing the browser.  When corrected it works fine for me.

Comment: True. Thank you very much. However, how is it that <a href=/liens/16/>Lorem Ipsum</a> even works ?

Comment: Possibly the part that's getting confused is in the JavaScript or somewhere in different parts of the DOM rendering logic, allowing a hard-coded element to render one way and a dynamically created one to render another.  The lesson here is simply to always use valid HTML, otherwise the behavior of the invalid HTML is undefined.